# Toast method for displaying messages

Tags: java, android, android-toast

I created a method for toast the problem is in some cases I want to display a toast message with an integer and sometimes I want to display toast message without the integer. I know this could be made possible by creating two separate functions but is it possible with one method itself.

```java
public void maketoast(String string, Integer inte){
    Toast.makeText(this, string+inte, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
```

The following are the cases of the method call :

```
maketoast("Greater than ",2);
```

```
maketoast("Greater ",null);
```

Output:
In first call, I need the output as "Greater than 2"
In the second call I need the output as "Greater" but currently I am getting "Greater null"

Answer (score 3):

Java has a [ternary operator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%3F:). Using it will help to abbreviate your code:

```
public void maketoast(String string, Integer inte){
    Toast.makeText(this, inte != null ? string+inte : string, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Adding null to a string converts null to "null". I recommend this

```
public void maketoast(String string, Integer inte){
    if(inte == null) 
      Toast.makeText(this, string, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    else
      Toast.makeText(this, string+inte, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
```